# IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets preserving the structure of the destination sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Suppose that we have the following Google Sheet (called `File_1`):

[image]

And we import all the columns (A to C) via `IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...", "Sheet1!A:C")` into another sheet (called `File_2`), which also contains an additional column `New_col` with some data in it:

[image]

Now, suppose that the source sheet changes like this, i.e., a new row is added in-between the existing rows:

[image]

The destination sheet will become like this, in essence keeping Column D in its previous state and 'breaking' the relation of the 'test' value in cell D2 with the A1-B1-C1 row.

[image]

What I would like to have instead is the following destination sheet:

[image]

Is there a way to do that from within Google Sheets?

Comment: Is col D hard-keyed? If not, which column would it be related to? A `VLOOKUP()` + `QUERY()` would probably solve it. If that is entered, I'm afraid you'd have to resort to `GAS`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you separate the information of the two sheets? Could you share a sample sheet of the actual data displayed on the two sheets you are working on?

Comment: Thanks a lot [onit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11832197/onit) and [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17390082/gabriel-carballo) for your responses. Unfortunately, I cannot share the actual data, as it is proprietary. In essence, the structure in the "source" sheet cannot be modified in any way; only rows can be added/removed. This is why I decided to create a "clone" sheet which would hold the source data along with a few additional columns, which would hold hard-keyed information. Unfortunately, I cannot think of a "logic" for using `VLOOKUP()` & I am not sure I can avoid `GAS`.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing how formula results get misaligned with manually entered data. There is no turn-key solution to work around the issue. Lance has given a thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases.

Comment: That's an extremely interesting find [doubleunary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13045193/doubleunary) - many thanks for this! I will try to implement this solution and will post my feedback right after.

Answer (score 0):

I created some custom code to solve this problem for our use-case:

https://github.com/giantswarm/gapps-automation/tree/main/sticky-rows

It amounts to doing an INNER JOIN on the two ranges (dynamic and sticky) and sorting the sticky range (with manual data) accordingly.